# Keep the original order of media elements in angular2-masonry plugin

Tags: angular, masonry, angular-masonry

I'm using an angular2-masonry plugin for an angular project, where I need to display the media without changing its order. There is no option available for the angular2-masonry plugin. So is there any way to make it happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to wait for all the images to be loaded before the brick are added using `useImagesLoaded`, without the dimensions masonry is unable to maintain the desired arrangement.

To add `useImagesLoaded`:

Include this in your .angular-cli.json import src or in the index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Had the use Image attribute set to true:

```
<masonry [useImagesLoaded]="true"></masonry>
```

Another option would be to use `setTimeout` to call `reloadItems` and `layout`:

One way to do this would be to first reference the component:

```
@ViewChild(AngularMasonry) private masonry: AngularMasonry;
```

Then handle the event:

```
itemsLoadHandler() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.masonry.reloadItems();
    this.masonry.layout();
  });
}
```

You can also listen for these events:

```
// Outputs
@Output() layoutComplete: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
@Output() removeComplete: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.masonry.on('layoutComplete', (items: any) => {
    this.layoutComplete.emit(items);
  });
  this.masonry.on('removeComplete', (items: any) => {
    this.removeComplete.emit(items);
  });
}
```

Hope that helps